# How to create favorites within a wiki?

Tags: mediawiki

I use a wiki with 20 other ppl. I have my own username. How can I set some favorites to special pages in the wiki within the wiki? Do I really have to create a page within the wiki called "my favorites"?

Comment: I'm flagging this as off topic (nothing to do with programming), but you can use the star function to put pages on your watch list (use `Special:EditWatchlist` to view them alphabetically). Otherwise, creating a page called "User:MyUserName/Favorites", or something like that, sounds like a good idea.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [watchlist](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Watchlist) or install the [Collection extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Collection).

Comment: That's how I do it: watchlist